# md5 hashes in PowerShell (or CMD) with relative file paths

Tags: powershell, cmd

I would like to write the md5 hashes for all files in a directory and its subdirectories to a file. Ideally, replicating the output of the unix command `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +` (i.e. two columns: hashes and relative file paths).

I was looking at the CMD command `CertUtil -hashfile afile.txt MD5`
but I got stuck with the full file paths given by `dir /A:-D /B /S`.
I found the following response using PowerShell: https://superuser.com/a/1249418. I've used CMD only rarely and this is my first attempt at PowerShell.

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem "*.*" -Recurse | Resolve-Path -Relative | Tee-Object -Variable y) | select hash | Out-File C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYFOLDER\temphashes.txt
$x = (Get-Content C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYFOLDER\temphashes.txt).ToLower() | select -skip 3 | ?{$_.Trim(" `t")}
$i = 0; $x | ForEach-Object {($_, $y[$i]) -join " "; $i++} | Out-File C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYFOLDER\hashes.txt
```

Is there a better way to get the hashes and relative paths in PowerShell (or CMD)? Or at least, can the intermediate file `temphashes.txt' be overwritten with the final output?

Edit: Can the hashes be made lowercase, and the headings and extra trailing blank lines be removed (see the second line in my attempt) so the file looks like:

```
d41d8ce98f00b204e9800988ecf8427e .\aSubDirectory\anotherfile.txt
4615fd7b904c04e94cbeced23361c778 .\afile.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this get you what you're looking for?

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "*.*" -Recurse

$Result = ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    Get-FileHash $File -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,@{N='Path';E={$_.Path | Resolve-Path -Relative}}
} 

$Result | Out-File C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYFOLDER\hashes.txt
```

Explanation:

- Retrieves all the files using `Get-ChildItem` in to a variable named `$Files`.
- Loops through each file and uses `Get-FileHash` to retrieve the FileHash, which also returns the full path as path.
- Pass this result to `Select-Object` and select just the Hash Property while using a [Calculated Property](https://foxdeploy.com/2014/05/18/working-out-select-object-with-calculated-properties/) to return `Path` as the relative path.
- The results of the ForEach loop are returned to a `$Result` variable which is then output to a file with `Out-File`.

Comment: To get the hash in lower case `Select-Object @{n='Hash';e={$_.Hash.ToLower()}},...` to drop the header from `$Result` => `$Result | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\MYFOLDER\hashes.txt`

Comment: Thank you Mark Wragg, LotPings and mhu for your quick replies. I further modified the $Result line to remove the blank lines likes so
($Result | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim() | Out-File C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYFOLDER\hashes.txt
   Also, ">" appears to work as an alias for "| Out-File".

Comment: Also, I found the option `-Autosize` for `Format-Table` helps to prevent longer file paths being cut off. Here's a one line version: `(Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (gci "*.*" -Recurse) | select @{N='Hash';E={$_.Hash.ToLower()}},@{N='Path';E={$_.Path | rvpa -Relative}} | ft -Autosize -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim() > $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\MYFOLDER\hashes.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | 
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
    Select-Object "Hash","Path" | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    Out-File -FilePath "files.txt"
```